# Should delete necessarily be the last statement in a destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

I ran into this piece of code in a (fairly well respected) book. 
(Note: "head" is a pointer of type Element)

```
Stack::~Stack(){
  while(head){
    Element *next = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = next;
   }
    return;
}
```

From my understanding, the delete keyword de-allocates the memory assigned to a pointer. How is it that the author has used the pointer in the next line, immediately after de-allocating it? 
This confused me a bit. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: To be clear, `delete` doesn't deallocate a pointer, it deallocates what the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How is it that the author has used the pointer in the next line, immediately after de-allocating it?

The author is reassigning the pointer to the next element.

The `delete` is *deallocating the memory pointed to by head*.  It doesn't "deallocate" the pointer itself - the pointer will still exist and being usable.

`head = next` then makes `head` point to a *different* chunk of memory (the chunk pointed to by `next`).  The memory that was deleted is never used again, so there is no issue.

Comment: Just to add onto this, modifying the pointer itself is not the same as modifying what the pointer points to..

Comment: I see. The head pointer still exists in memory. Makes sense, thanks.  My natural instinct is to then ask, what is "head" pointing to immediately after that statement is executed? Will the head pointer point to a garbage memory location, or will head be a NULL pointer?

Comment: @Sir `head` still points to the same memory location, it's just that you are no longer allowed to use that memory.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  Analogy:  the boss fired Bob yesterday; how is it that, today, there is someone at Bob's desk?

What is confusing is that, by the analogy, C++ syntax does not `delete Bob;` but rather `delete Bobs_desk;`—which actually means to delete the employee at Bob's desk, but does not get rid of the desk.

The boss remains free to seat someone else at Bob's desk once Bob has cleared out.  Do you follow?

Comment: Yep, makes sense. Delete simply deallocates the memory that the pointer in discussion is _pointing to_, but the pointer (which is probably sitting in another memory location), is safe. I suppose I will get a segmentation fault if I attempt to do something like this : 'next = *head'. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Well, `next=*head;` would not quite compile, but (assuming that `Element` is a copyable type),`*next=*head;` would exhibit undefined behavior at run time -- most likely a segmentation fault, as you say.  The line `next=head;` would of course work until one subsequently tried to dereference `next`, at which point there the undefined behavior, segmentation fault, etc., would again arise.